# Why are images inside my assets folder only displayed when the folder is outside the src-folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image

In two different ReactJS projects, I am working with images which are stored inside of an "assets"-folder. For some reason though, they are only found/displayed as long as the folder containing them is outside the source folder. Why is that?

Comment: React does not serve any image files. You have some webservers in the mix that make decisions like this, but this is not directly related to react.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about both projects it's not possible to say which specific part of the project is causing this. However, if the issue is that moving the assets folder around does not break things *until* you move it into the source folder, this will most likely be due to whichever deployment system you use not making raw source files available as assets.

If the issue is just that moving or renaming the assets folder prevents you from being able to access it, then that will be down to the configuration of your deployment process.